# c# regular expression getting specific string from string[CLOSE]

Tags: c#, regex

help i want to get the specific string from my string x="Glass      1      1000"; i want to get the string "Glass" only and save it to my string type.

```
 int[] quanvalue = new int[2];
                  int x1 = 0;
                  string type = "";
                  string x="Glass  1  1000";
                  string[] numbers = Regex.Split(x, @"\D+");
                  foreach (string value in numbers)
              {


                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                  {
                      int ib = int.Parse(value);
                      quanvalue[x1] = ib;
                      MessageBox.Show(quanvalue[0].ToString() + " " + quanvalue[1].ToString());
                      x1++;
                  }
                  else
                  {      
                      // i want to get string from here
                  }
```

Comment: As it stands the answer is `x = "Glass"` ... You need to define the logic you want to apply: is it the first word you want? The word that remains after removing all  digits?

Comment: sorry. i already edit that part . i need to get the "Glass" only in string x is this possible?

Comment: So you always want the *first word* from a string?

Comment: yes, i want to get the first word and save it to my string type  my code is extracting the word and digits in specific string

Comment: Does the string have an expected format, like a word followed by one or more numbers delimited by spaces?  Can you show all the expected types of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string sub = x.Substring(0, 5);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substring function to fetch the first 5 characters from x.
And save it in x itself